# Notifications on background tasks in NewRelic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, newrelic

I'd love to be notified when any of my background tasks causes an error. We use DJ on heroku and NewRelic is monitoring it very well, i can even see the errors themselves, i'm just not sure how to create a rule for an alert or a notification for these specific transactions (or for any background task error for that manner)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the agents, .Net, PHP, Java, and the like, New Relic alerts on only two events: *downtime events* and *low Apdex scores*.  The best you could do is pull a specific transaction out as a **Key Transaction** which would allow you to assign it an Apdex threshold that is different (usually lower)  than the main application so that if a small number of errors do occur it will lower the Apdex enough to create an alert.  Since key transaction Apdex scores feed into the main application Apdex score it will lower that one as well as a side effect.